# PHP avoid creating multiple pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Im a 3rd year IT student one of my modules is webdesign, so I am fairly new to the concept, in my assignment I need to create a booking system.

I have created the backend dashboard which looks like this, which brings me to my question.:

[image]

On the left vertical navbar on the image you can see the user has a number of options such as *view reservations*, *add new cars* etc

### MY QUESTION

Instead of having to create multiple pages such as `makereservation.php` or `addcars.php` which are all just really functions querying the DB to display result,

I would like to know ***is it not possible to keep only this one page (the dashboard) and call, append the function, inside the content section as the user clicks the corresponding link -- thus avoiding to create unnecessary extra pages.***

Hopes this make sense, please dont hesitate to ask should you need any further info

Comment: Yes. Reality is that any page could be split into various blocks, and while a "click" might load an entire page with slightly different content, your code does not need to be entirely duplicated. One step further would be to make the links trigger ajax calls to retrieve the corresponding content, and place that into the container via javascript, but that is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @sal yeah I thought some ajax would be needed which is unfortunately above my ability at the moment, do you perhaps have an example you could point me to that I Could use as a reference?

Comment: Here something with ajax, for which I would strongly encourage you to use jQuery: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/ . Something in plain php could be looked at here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159529/how-to-structure-template-system-using-plain-php

Comment: So are you just loading the content from a database? You could give all your links different id's and then trigger an event on an on click which performs an AJAX call to a main function which then retrieves the corresponding page content. There are other ways, but this is the simplest but not the prettiest... but many times simple always wins!

Comment: @TimBrownlaw EXACTLY what I was hoping to achieve I was hoping to append the links to the url, retrieving the result from the queries....any examples perhaps?

Comment: Well its one of those things you do in small steps... :) You've got the Big Picture, then you break it down... Have you tried anything yet before I rush off and try to come up with a solution...

Answer (score 1):

**query_to_db.php** is the only one page to do queries to DB and returns HTML result

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_GET["type"]) && !empty($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == 'makereservation'){
        //your page makereservation.php code
        // echo HTML result
    }else if(isset($_GET["type"]) && !empty($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] == 'addcars'){
        //your page addcars.php code
        // echo HTML result
    }
    ?>
```

and your html page

```
<ul>
<!--each link below has onclick='searcQuery("REQUEST_TYPE_HERE")'
 witch will make XHR request with GET method-->
<li><a href='#' onclick='searcQuery("makereservation")'>makereservation</a></li>
<li><a href='#' onclick='searcQuery("addcars")'>addcars</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='book-body'></div>
<script>
function searcQuery(typ){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //print result to the div #book-body
      document.getElementById("book-body").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "query_to_db.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send("&type="+typ);   
}
</script>
```